# Reactjs: Component will mount for loop

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, arraylist

In my Reactjs app, I have array of objects, each object has 2 properties:type and dates, dates is array and object has 2 properties: date and count.
I want to fetch API with for loop based on month and year, and this is my code.

```
componentWillMount(){
    var mon = Array.apply(0, Array(12)).map(function(_,i){return moment().month(i).format('M/YYYY')});
    var index = mon.indexOf(moment().format("M/YYYY"));
    var month = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        month.push(mon[i]);
    }
    var m = [];

for (var i = 0; i < month.length; i++) {
        getRoomAvail(month[i])
        .then(response =>{
        let res = response.data.data
        this.setState({
            data:res,
        })
        m.push(this.state.data);
        })
        this.setState({
            month: month[i]
        })
    }
    this.setState({
        arr: m
    })
    console.log(this.state.arr)
}
```

And this is result.

```
dates: […]
0: Object { date: "2017-7-1", count: 10 }
1: Object { date: "2017-7-2", count: 10 }
2: Object { date: "2017-7-3", count: 10 }
3: Object { date: "2017-7-4", count: 10 }
4: Object { date: "2017-7-5", count: 10 }
5: Object { date: "2017-7-6", count: 10 }
6: Object { date: "2017-7-7", count: 10 }
7: Object { date: "2017-7-8", count: 10 }
8: Object { date: "2017-7-9", count: 10 }
9: Object { date: "2017-7-10", count: 10 }
10: Object { date: "2017-7-11", count: 10 }
11: Object { date: "2017-7-12", count: 10 }
12: Object { date: "2017-7-13", count: 10 }
13: Object { date: "2017-7-14", count: 10 }
14: Object { date: "2017-7-15", count: 10 }
15: Object { date: "2017-7-16", count: 10 }
16: Object { date: "2017-7-17", count: 10 }
17: Object { date: "2017-7-18", count: 10 }
18: Object { date: "2017-7-19", count: 10 }
19: Object { date: "2017-7-20", count: 10 }
20: Object { date: "2017-7-21", count: 10 }
21: Object { date: "2017-7-22", count: 10 }
22: Object { date: "2017-7-23", count: 10 }
23: Object { date: "2017-7-24", count: 10 }
24: Object { date: "2017-7-25", count: 10 }
25: Object { date: "2017-7-26", count: 10 }
26: Object { date: "2017-7-27", count: 10 }
27: Object { date: "2017-7-28", count: 10 }
28: Object { date: "2017-7-29", count: 10 }
29: Object { date: "2017-7-30", count: 10 }
30: Object { date: "2017-7-31", count: 10 }
length: 31
__proto__: Array []
type: "Superior"
__proto__: Object { … }
1: Object { type: "Superior View Ocean", dates: […] }
2: Object { type: "Deluxe", dates: […] }
3: Object { type: "Cottage", dates: […] }
length: 4
__proto__: Array []
11: […]
0: {…}
dates: […]
0: Object { date: "2017-10-1", count: 10 }
1: Object { date: "2017-10-2", count: 10 }
2: Object { date: "2017-10-3", count: 10 }
3: Object { date: "2017-10-4", count: 10 }
4: Object { date: "2017-10-5", count: 10 }
5: Object { date: "2017-10-6", count: 10 }
6: Object { date: "2017-10-7", count: 10 }
7: Object { date: "2017-10-8", count: 10 }
8: Object { date: "2017-10-9", count: 10 }
9: Object { date: "2017-10-10", count: 10 }
10: Object { date: "2017-10-11", count: 10 }
11: Object { date: "2017-10-12", count: 10 }
12: Object { date: "2017-10-13", count: 10 }
13: Object { date: "2017-10-14", count: 10 }
14: Object { date: "2017-10-15", count: 10 }
15: Object { date: "2017-10-16", count: 10 }
16: Object { date: "2017-10-17", count: 10 }
17: Object { date: "2017-10-18", count: 10 }
18: Object { date: "2017-10-19", count: 10 }
19: Object { date: "2017-10-20", count: 10 }
20: Object { date: "2017-10-21", count: 10 }
21: Object { date: "2017-10-22", count: 10 }
22: Object { date: "2017-10-23", count: 10 }
23: Object { date: "2017-10-24", count: 10 }
24: Object { date: "2017-10-25", count: 10 }
25: Object { date: "2017-10-26", count: 10 }
26: Object { date: "2017-10-27", count: 10 }
27: Object { date: "2017-10-28", count: 10 }
28: Object { date: "2017-10-29", count: 10 }
29: Object { date: "2017-10-30", count: 10 }
30: Object { date: "2017-10-31", count: 10 }
length: 31
```

on array of object above, object date is not arrange, and when I refresh my browser data json above is change like a random.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: what is `mon`, `month`, `m`, `arr`, `data`.... ?? Pls be specific with your qstn. Also remember that async code (API call) might not run in the order you expect